# Get file object from file Input

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a react-bootstrap file input with jquery `fileupload()`. With straight jquery I would do `$('#fileUpload').prop('files')` to get the files to pass to the fileupload call. However, I don't know how to get the files correctly with react-bootstrap.

```
<Input type='file' label='Upload' accept='.txt' ref='fileUpload' buttonAfter={uploadFileButton}/>
```

Comment: @Daniel I used my answer below. What issue are you having?

Comment: See it does not work for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/danyaljj/b1fhnb6q/2/

Comment: @Daniel You can't access this.refs outside of the react class 'Hello'. Your error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileUpload' of undefined" is saying this.refs is undefined, not fileUpload. You need to put the reference in a function inside the class, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/0ttmh4hs/

Comment: @Daneil No worries, React's learning curve can be quite frustrating. Can you undo your downvote if that was you, that way people will know it's the correct answer.

Comment: it says "you cannot upvote unless it is edited". Could you edit something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The more current version of this would be something like:

```js
function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  const handleFileSelected = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const files = Array.from(e.target.files)
    console.log("files:", files)
  }

  return (
    <input onChange={handleFileSelected} type="file" />
  )
}
```

The attribute is found on `e.target.files` which you can get from the `onChange` event.

EDIT: Removed unnecessary ref code, hat tip Mark in comments

Comment: The useRef hook is not needed, the onChange handler is all that's needed

Comment: Thanks @MarkJackson I've updated the code to reflect that improvement

Answer (score 27):

The ref string attribute is [considered legacy](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), and will most likely be deprecated at some point in the future. The way to do this now is with a callback ref. Below I demonstrate using an ES6 arrow function.

Change your input element to:

```
<Input 
  type='file' label='Upload' accept='.txt' 
  buttonAfter={uploadFileButton} 
  ref={(ref) => this.fileUpload = ref}
/>
```

Then you can use:

`const file = this.fileUpload.files[0];`

And so on.

Comment: Have any idea on how to do this on a FormControl element, considering Input is deprecated?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer due to the new changes with React 15 :)

Answer (score 11):

I solved file upload like this for `React-Bootstrap` with a custom looking button:

```
addFile = (event: any): void => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
}

<FormGroup>
    <ControlLabel htmlFor="fileUpload" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}><h3><Label bsStyle="success">Add file</Label></h3>
        <FormControl
            id="fileUpload"
            type="file"
            accept=".pdf"
            onChange={this.addFile}
            style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
    </ControlLabel>
</FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 10):

It's pretty straight forward; I completely missed this:

```
var files = this.refs.fileUpload.getInputDOMNode().files;
```

Comment: Could you share where you found this answer? I'm also using React-Bootstrap to build my app, but it's kinda hard to find resources that teach how to interact with data using react-bootstrap.

Comment: @T.O I think I figured it out myself. For most of my React issues, I just pieced together knowledge of html, jquery, etc and the basic information about React and bootstrap I could find on their sites and on SO.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the file object by binding an event handler to the onChange event of the HTML file input.

Here is a quick example using a functional component:

```
import React from 'react'

function UploadForm(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="docx" onChange={setFile.bind(this)} />
      <input type="button" onClick={postFile} value="Upload" />
    </div>
  )
  function postFile(event) {   
    // HTTP POST  
  }
  function setFile(event) {
    // Get the details of the files
    console.log(event.target.files)
  }
}

export default UploadForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [fahad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39778095), if you can't use an arrow function (due to older browser support, or for some other reason), you must bind the React context to the function.

```
<Input type='file' label='Upload' accept='.txt'
  buttonAfter={uploadFileButton}
  ref={ function(ref) { this.fileUpload = ref }.bind(this) }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
let file = this.refs.fileUpload.files[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the file that was uploaded using ref then you can do it as follow:
`fileUpload.current.files[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I am using react bootstrap and finds that files is an javaScript object not array type so we have to access it like a key value where key is the index i.e, length - 1

this code might help

```
const _handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
const file = Object(event.currentTarget.files)[0];
console.log(file);
};
```