# Uploading a file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, file-upload

I'm just trying to upload a file from my 'input' tag into javascript. When i double click my file in the pop up to select it, javascript is telling me the event obj doesnt contain any of the image file information. I believe file info is supposed to be located in event.target.files[i] but thats not the case as you can see below in the return JSON event object.

JSX:

```
render() {
  return(
    <input className="account-settings-title-input" type="file" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
  );
}

private handleChange(event: any) {
    const util = require('util');
    console.log('Selected file:', util.inspect(event));
}
```

JSON of event object which should have contained the file data:

```
  Selected file: { dispatchConfig: 
 { phasedRegistrationNames: { bubbled: 'onChange', captured: 'onChangeCapture' 
 },
 dependencies: 
  [ 'topBlur',
    'topChange',
    'topClick',
    'topFocus',
    'topInput',
    'topKeyDown',
    'topKeyUp',
    'topSelectionChange' ] },
 _targetInst: 
 { tag: 5,
 key: null,
 type: 'input',
 stateNode: 
  { '__reactInternalInstance$wgylo8v4wb': [Circular],
    '__reactEventHandlers$wgylo8v4wb': [Object],
    _wrapperState: [Object],
    value: [Getter/Setter],
    _valueTracker: [Object] },
 return: 
  { tag: 5,
    key: null,
    type: 'div',
    stateNode: [Object],
    return: [Object],
    child: [Object],
    sibling: null,
    index: 0,
    ref: null,
    pendingProps: null,
    memoizedProps: [Object],
    updateQueue: null,
    memoizedState: null,
    internalContextTag: 0,
    effectTag: 0,
    nextEffect: null,
    firstEffect: null,
    lastEffect: null,
    expirationTime: 0,
    alternate: null },
 child: null,
 sibling: null,
 index: 2,
 ref: null,
 pendingProps: null,
 memoizedProps: 
  { className: 'account-settings-title-input',
    type: 'file',
    onChange: [Function: onChange] },
 updateQueue: null,
 memoizedState: null,
 internalContextTag: 0,
 effectTag: 0,
 nextEffect: null,
 firstEffect: null,
 lastEffect: null,
 expirationTime: 0,
 alternate: null },
 nativeEvent: { isTrusted: [Getter] },
 type: 'change',
 target: 
 { '__reactInternalInstance$wgylo8v4wb': 
  { tag: 5,
    key: null,
    type: 'input',
    stateNode: [Circular],
    return: [Object],
    child: null,
    sibling: null,
    index: 2,
    ref: null,
    pendingProps: null,
    memoizedProps: [Object],
    updateQueue: null,
    memoizedState: null,
    internalContextTag: 0,
    effectTag: 0,
    nextEffect: null,
    firstEffect: null,
    lastEffect: null,
    expirationTime: 0,
    alternate: null },
  '__reactEventHandlers$wgylo8v4wb': 
  { className: 'account-settings-title-input',
    type: 'file',
    onChange: [Function: onChange] },
  _wrapperState: 
  { initialChecked: undefined,
    initialValue: undefined,
    controlled: false },
  value: [Getter/Setter],
  _valueTracker: 
  { getValue: [Function: getValue],
    setValue: [Function: setValue],
    stopTracking: [Function: stopTracking] } },
  currentTarget: 
  { '__reactInternalInstance$wgylo8v4wb': 
  { tag: 5,
    key: null,
    type: 'input',
    stateNode: [Circular],
    return: [Object],
    child: null,
    sibling: null,
    index: 2,
    ref: null,
    pendingProps: null,
    memoizedProps: [Object],
    updateQueue: null,
    memoizedState: null,
    internalContextTag: 0,
    effectTag: 0,
    nextEffect: null,
    firstEffect: null,
    lastEffect: null,
    expirationTime: 0,
    alternate: null },
 '__reactEventHandlers$wgylo8v4wb': 
  { className: 'account-settings-title-input',
    type: 'file',
    onChange: [Function: onChange] },
 _wrapperState: 
  { initialChecked: undefined,
    initialValue: undefined,
    controlled: false },
 value: [Getter/Setter],
 _valueTracker: 
  { getValue: [Function: getValue],
    setValue: [Function: setValue],
    stopTracking: [Function: stopTracking] } },
 eventPhase: 3,
 bubbles: true,
 cancelable: false,
 timeStamp: 15921.499999705702,
 defaultPrevented: false,
 isTrusted: true,
 isDefaultPrevented: [Function],
 isPropagationStopped: [Function],
 _dispatchListeners: [Function: onChange],
 _dispatchInstances: 
 { tag: 5,
 key: null,
 type: 'input',
 stateNode: 
  { '__reactInternalInstance$wgylo8v4wb': [Circular],
    '__reactEventHandlers$wgylo8v4wb': [Object],
    _wrapperState: [Object],
    value: [Getter/Setter],
    _valueTracker: [Object] },
 return: 
  { tag: 5,
    key: null,
    type: 'div',
    stateNode: [Object],
    return: [Object],
    child: [Object],
    sibling: null,
    index: 0,
    ref: null,
    pendingProps: null,
    memoizedProps: [Object],
    updateQueue: null,
    memoizedState: null,
    internalContextTag: 0,
    effectTag: 0,
    nextEffect: null,
    firstEffect: null,
    lastEffect: null,
    expirationTime: 0,
    alternate: null },
 child: null,
 sibling: null,
 index: 2,
 ref: null,
 pendingProps: null,
 memoizedProps: 
  { className: 'account-settings-title-input',
    type: 'file',
    onChange: [Function: onChange] },
 updateQueue: null,
 memoizedState: null,
 internalContextTag: 0,
 effectTag: 0,
 nextEffect: null,
 firstEffect: null,
 lastEffect: null,
 expirationTime: 0,
 alternate: null } }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file object from file Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483645/get-file-object-from-file-input)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a reference to the input like this:

```
<input type='file' ref={(ref) => this.fileUpload = ref}/>
```

Once you have the reference, you don't have to listen for the onChange event as the 'files' array will be populated, being able to get the file like this:

```
const file = this.fileUpload.files[0];
```

You can change the index of the array to access multiples files if you upload multiple files at once.

Comment: I get that same JSON object result for this.fileUpload :S