# Send data and file from React to NodeJS using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to send data with a file from my React post to NodeJS.

In React I have a form with some inputs of type string and number and an input of type File

```
<Input type="file" name="file" id="file" 
   innerRef={register()} 
/>
```

I send the form submit data to NodeJS using axios:
The data is an object with my data:

```
const data = {
   amount: data.debitAmt,
   invoiceDate: data.invoiceDate,
   memo: data.memo,
   file: data.file
};

await axios.post(`${url.REQ_URL}/bills/add`, {
   headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
   },
   data
});
```

When I check the NodeJS, the file is an empty object:

```
exports.add = async (req, res, next) => {
   const data = req.body.data || req.body;
   console.log(data);  
}
```

The log shows:

```
{
  amount: '10',
  invoiceDate: '2021-04-02',
  memo: '',
  file: { '0': {} }
}
```

Why it is not sending the file? Do I need a separated axios.post just for the file?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62999947/12485722

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it did not.